# Read received data via /dev/spi*

Tags: java, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi

I'm using an ariag25 board with emdebian (kernel v3.11.6) and I want to communicate via SPI with an other device. I enabled the SPI driver via the device tree and I have all my 6 spi* via /dev/.

```
spi0: spi@f0000000 {
            status = "okay";
            interrupts = <13 4 5>;
            cs-gpios = <&pioC 10 0>, <&pioC 11 0>, <&pioC 12 0>, 
                       <&pioC 13 0>, <&pioC 14 0>, <&pioC 15 0>;
            CCVE1@0 {
            compatible = "spidev";
            spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
            reg = <0>;
            };

            /**etc.**/

            CCVE6@5 {
            compatible = "spidev";
            spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
            reg = <5>;
            };
        };
```

With an echo command ( echo 111 > /dev/spidev32766.0 ), I can send data (confirmed by an oscilloscope) but I can't open the device for read (cat /dev/spidev32766.0 returned, in french, "cat: spidev32766.0: Message trop long").
Do you have any idea how I can read the data ? At first I wanna try to open the file via Java to read/write. For write no problems (file.write() works) but read return an exception.

Comment: spi is full duplex so common io model won't work. you need to use `ioctl` in c to actually do the io operations.

Comment: to explain your question, `echo` works since for the write semantics, it's ok to ignore the message sent by slave. but for `cat`, if you try to read from spi, you need to send data as well at the same time, so the semantics doesn't let through.

Comment: There is an example in the kernel source tree *Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c*

Comment: I'll try `ioctl()` and the spidev_test.c, thank's